Unable to retrieve the metadata for Standard picklist field Status on PatientMedicalProcedure, how can I retrieve it?
Unable to retrieve the metadata for Standard picklist field Status on PatientMedicalProcedure, how can I retrieve it?
We have tried
sf force:source:retrieve -m StandardValueSet:PatientMedicalProcedureStatus

and it didn't work
Preparing retrieve request... done
=== Retrieved Source

No results found
=== Retrieved Source Warnings

 FILE NAME              PROBLEM                                                                                 
 ────────────────────── ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 
 unpackaged/package.xml Entity of type 'StandardValueSet' named 'PatientMedicalProcedureStatus' cannot be found

Also tried
 sf force:source:retrieve -m StandardValueSet:PatientMedicalProcedure.Status

or other combination but nothing worked.
Also, list metadata call doesn't work on StandardValueSet
sfdx force:mdapi:listmetadata -m StandardValueSet     

Warning: No metadata found for type: StandardValueSet in org


The doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm says it should be PMPStatus.
sf force:source:retrieve -m StandardValueSet:PMPStatus

